# I want to restrict users to download it for at least 2 weeks because app is in development stage. What should I do now?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, appgallery-connect

I have uploaded and pushed my app under test environment but I went online and available across the globe. Now I want to restrict users to download it for at least 2 weeks because app is in development stage. What should I do now ?

Answer (score 1):

If you no longer want to make an app available for users, or if issues occur in your released app version, you can apply to remove the app from Huawei App Gallery. After an app is removed from sale, users will not be able to find the app on Huawei App Gallery and the app version changes to the draft state in App Gallery Connect. If you want to release the app again, you can edit the app version in draft state and release the edited version.

[image: Preview]

Note:

1- You can only remove a released app version.

2- Removing an app will not release the package name used by the app. A package name can be released only after you delete the app.

For more info, please refer to the [guidelines](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/app/agc-remove_app).